# Tidyverse Solution: Sum across rows by group, preserve other columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID Unique_Val Group_val
1   4          5
1   6          5
2   8          3
2   4          3
```

Note that the data is in a long format where the group_val is duplicated for each row with the same ID. I'd like to get output as follows:

```
ID Unique_Val Group_val
1  10         5
2  12         3
```

Where we sum over the Unique_val for each ID, but preserve the Group_val. I know I could do some nasty looping, but I imagine there is an ellegent dpylr solution I can't figure out. Seems like summarize + group_by, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
data %>% group_by(ID, Group_val) %>% summarise(Unique_Val = sum(Unique_Val))
```

You just need to group by your two variables.

Comment: Ah... always something silly and easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(Unique_Val ~ ID + Group_val, data, FUN = sum)
```